# Pagination :- Load next 5 images in the adapter when scrolled out item reached count of 5

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, android-adapter

Hello im trying to include a pagination method in  my recylerview but dont know exactly how to do it , What i want is when the fragments start 10 items(images) should load in the adapter (which currently load all the items available in the database) and when the scrolled out items reaches the count of 5 and adapter only have 5 items to show the user next 5 items will load so the adapter will maintain a total items of 10 and the cycle continues ,so the user will never reach the end of list and wait until the next images are loaded

i have implemented a method when the currentItems+scrolledOutItems == totalItems(adapter) more items will load and it is all messed up nothing is working btw , and also i dont want that when all items are scrolled next items will load

here what i imeplemented

```
public List<Upload> mUploads;
    PostAdapter_Home postsAdapter;
    RecyclerView verticalRecyclerView;
    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;
    Boolean isScrolling = false;
    int currentItems, totalItems, scrolledOutItems;

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        MaterialToolbar materialToolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        materialToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(toolbarItemClickListener);
        verticalRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHome);
        shimmerFrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmerEffect);

//        this is for one item per scroll
        SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(verticalRecyclerView);

        verticalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        );
        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
        postsAdapter = new PostAdapter_Home(getContext(), mUploads);
        verticalRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
        verticalRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(Home_Fragment.saved_position);
        verticalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    isScrolling = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                currentItems = postsAdapter.getChildCount()
                totalItems = postsAdapter.getItemCount();
                scrolledOutItems = postsAdapter.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if (isScrolling && (scrolledOutItems + currentItems == totalItems)) {
                    getData();
                }

            }
        });
        shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
        return view;
    }


    private void getData() {
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                    shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    verticalRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mUploads.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        assert upload != null;
                        upload.setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        mUploads.add(upload);


                    }

                }

                //notify the adapter
                postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paging 3 library. It has support for pagination and recyclerview so you won't have to manage the scrolling yourself.

You can find how to implement Paging 3 in this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/12244218-paging-library-for-android-with-kotlin-creating-infinite-lists). I have tried it and it works as expected. The tutorial is in Kotlin though.

Comment: thanks for the info but java will be better for me , can you please suggest me good librarys for paging (Java) which is easy to implement

Comment: You can implement Paging library in Java, I think you can find many tutorials in google by searching 'Paging 3 java example'